# How to search for a New York area 20th century building by its appearance?

Tags: 20th-century, new-york-state, photo-identification, 1950s, building

I have these photos I inherited from my father of a building near a water feature that was taken around June 1958 in the New York City area, in a roll of film that is right before some photos of West Point.  I tried searching [Google Images with a bunch of terms](https://www.google.com/search?q=white+historical+building+garden+west+point&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjg7di11IPmAhUVmp4KHS4PABYQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=white+historical+building+garden+west+point) in various combinations and was unsuccessful.  The terms I tried included:

- Botanical Gardens
- New York
- Building
- Historical
- White
- Hudson River
- West Point

There is a building that probably can be used to identify the location:

[image]

The next photo shows the same building in the background behind the tree and has a water feature with statue of a human figure, that from prior picture's vantage point appears to be raised above the surrounding area by several feet:

[image]

Ideas on how to better search for a building by its appearance?

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, the Hudson Valley is full of historic mansions with landscaped grounds — many of them white — so your search terms should mention things that are *unique* about this one (e.g. "white" is unlikely to help, but "Gothic windows" might), and *notable* (e.g. "Cupid statue" is unlikely to help [even if it were a Cupid, which I guess it's not, ha]).

I just spent... I don't know, probably an hour... down this rabbit hole. Here's my liveblog of how I went about it. I didn't find your location (sorry!), but your question was actually about *how one might approach the search*, so in that sense, this is a good answer to the question you asked. ;)

The most notable things about the building in the photo are:

- Gothic windows
- that stepped roofline
- that square tower on the left

The first two features are shared with Washington Irving's [Sunnyside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunnyside_%28Tarrytown,_New_York%29); the Wikipedia article tells me that the name for the stepped roofline is [*stepped gable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepped_gable) or *corbie gable*. It's also known as a [Dutch gable](https://buildingsofnewengland.com/tag/dutch-gable/), which is just more confirmation that we're looking at the Hudson Valley.

At this point I started Google-Image-searching for `"stepped gable" mansion and grounds "west point"`, `"dutch gable" mansion and grounds "west point"`, `"corbie" mansion and grounds "west point"`, `gable tower gothic hudson`,...

The problem, of course, is that the results for "show me a mansion with a stepped gable and a tower" are overwhelmingly polluted with the stepped-gable-and-tower-having Sunnyside. But we don't want to add `-sunnyside` to the search because we don't want to exclude a useful page that just happens to say "Notice how the tower and gable on [the mansion we care about] resembles Washington Irving's Sunnyside..."

I ended up on a page for [*Hudson Valley Ruins*](http://www.hudsonvalleyruins.org/contents.html), organized by county, which suggested to me that I should find out what county West Point is in: Orange (again with the Dutch!). This is a vague term, but the biggest town in Orange County seems to be Newburgh, so I tried `"stepped gable" tower newburgh`. This turned up ["On the Origins of the American Porch"](https://doi.org/10.1086/504855) (2005), which had lots of photos — none of the building we're looking for — and suggested the additional terms `parapet` or `crenellation` (on the tower: a distinguishing feature compared to Sunnyside's Spanish-style tower) and `enclosed porch`. Unfortunately all of those terms are also used for regular single-family houses, so I brought back `mansion`: now we're somewhere like `gable tower parapet mansion "new york"`, which is too generic.

With `dutch "square tower" historic mansion hudson "new york"` I found another JSTOR article: ["Castles on the Hudson"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1180626) (1979). As before: lots of photos of other mansions, no luck on yours.

Suppose it was torn down? `mansion destroyed 1960s hudson new york`, `mansion destroyed 1970s hudson new york`, etc. Still no luck.

It's possible that the mansion and grounds were open to the public circa 1958 but are no longer public; maybe there's a good way to search for "mansion house tourist attractions in New York circa 1958," but I'm starting to burn out. Tourist attractions might issue postcards: `mansion postcard Hudson Valley New York 1950s`? The house might be on the Register of Historic Places (but with that ugly enclosed porch I'm not hopeful; and also it'd have to still exist).

Anyway, if you ever find out, maybe you'll come back and update this post with your answer. :)